# can .webloc file icon show a useful web page preview?

Tags: macos, icon

Assuming Finder --> View --> View Options --> Show Icon Preview is enabled, is it possible for a .webloc file icon to show a preview of the referenced web-page?

I think the browser would have to do this, when I drag from the browser URL box to the desktop.  But so far, with multiple popular browsers, I see nothing but not-very-informative standard icons.  For example, the Safari compass.

Does any popular browser support this, say,  through a preference setting or an add-in?

Motivation:  I can now sort through a bunch of TextEdit files by putting them in a folder, view them as icons, and using the Finder option to increase the icon size until enough is visible -- document "shape" and larger text. Why not .weblocs?

Obviously, the browser-created .webloc file name should be useful, but often it is not, and --when I'm collecting a bunch of .webloc files for reference use-- it is a bit of a pain to have to edit the name of each.

Obviously the icon content would be a snapshot at the time of collecting the .webloc.  I assume there is no way to see the current content.  OK by me.  Thinking about the potential for just a minute, this possibility seems at minimum creepy ... to very undesirable, unless completely under user control.  Well, anyway, the kinds of reference pages I want to collect and sort through generally don't change much.

TIA

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is achieved via Quicklook in Mac OS.  **Question**: does quicklook work on the files in question?  Highlight the file in finder and smack the spacebar.  Do you get a quick look at the file? This is the default behavior as of Lion.

Comment: Wow, no matter how much I explore MacOS, someone can always tell me about more cool features.  In this case, Quicklook.   However, what I'd like to see is a static thumbnail of the window Quicklook generates. (Hmmm, does Quicklook fetch the current page content or use a cached version?)

Answer (score 5):

I did finally locate an application that provides the solution you are looking for.  The application isn't hands-free initially as it is a command line program.

[setWeblocThumb](http://hasseg.org/setWeblocThumb/) generates custom icon consisting of a preview of the web page that the webloc file points to.  It *does not* do this universally.  You'll need to

1. point it at folders that you'd like it to watch
2. Assign a [folder action](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/?cb=1) to the folder that you'd like setWeblocThumb to watch and have it run setWeblocThumb.

It's fairly straightforward, but *is* a bit more than simply downloading and installing an application.  The good news is that it's free.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  No worry that practical use requires a bit more work; I'll probably want to tweak it anyway.  Added bonus:  availability of source.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "HetimaWebThumbnail.qlgenerator" QuickLook plugin from SafariStand did this. I'm not sure if it works with the newest Safari version though. I don't use Safari anymore.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.   I'm very leery of plug-ins that require additional plug-ins.  (This one requires something called  SIMBL).  Not a lot about this plug-in on the Web and some of it is a bit discouraging.  I guess I'll stick with Quicklook (per above).